# What are the hops varieties Sticklebract & Galena?

Tags: hops, ingredients

A homebrew shop has just opened up near me (hooray!). Browsing their wares I saw two hops varieties unknown  to me: Sticklebract (I think this is the correct name) and Galena. They seem to have been grown in Italy which surprised me. Has anyone used these hops in a brew and what are their characteristics?

Comment: Glelena is typically American grown and very common; I'd expect it in your homebrew store.  Stickelbract is a New Zealand hop in the 12% alpha acid range.  You might consider editing your question, removing the Italy reference.

Comment: Thanks, but Galena is certainly not common in Europe (I am in Madrid). I have never come across it here. Why should I remove the Italy reference? Since Italy does not have a strong brewing tradition (but I am happy to be corrected on this) it was interesting to see that they were coming from Italy.

Comment: Please forgive my American-centric views.  I must learn that just because we're conversing in English, it doesn't mean we all are in North America.  My bad.  Although it is an "American hop", you're Galena is probably really grown in Italy after all.

Comment: No problem Dale :) I am a Brit in Spain and I walked into this brew shop and didn't recognise *any* of the hops!

Answer (score 6):

[Galena](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Galena) is an US bittering hop, 11-14% AA described as "citrusy. fruity/black-currant similar to Bullion".

[Sticklebract](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Sticklebract) is a New Zealand dual-purpose hop, 10.5-14.5% AA, described as "high selinine content and a piney, citrusy aroma".

Comment: Thanks for the reply - have you actually used them in brews?

Comment: No, unfortunately.  I've recently been collecting qual. and quant. information on hops for brew-journal.com.